# Return value of a function in Visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

HI,

I am very much new to using Visual studio.

I am trying to debug an application.
where i came across a statement like below:

```
double tmp = 
myPart->bat_qty() * timeFactor / myPart->AUB() * myPart->UCost * myAIM->param->myAnalysisParams->wd_year;
```

in VS when put the cursor at

```
timeFactor
myPart->UCost
myAIM->param->myAnalysisParams->wd_year
```

it shows the corresponding values.But Not of the values returned by

```
myPart->bat_qty()
myPart->AUB()
```

what is the easiest way to find the values returned by those functions.
Apologies if this appears to be a cliche kind of a query.But i am completely new to VS.
I need a better way to find the values returned without editing the files for storing the values in some temporary variables.i mean i sould not edit the files.

Comment: I want to know it as well (if possible for VS2005). I think your best bet is to inspect the value of `eax` register.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest way is just to enter `myPart->bat_qty()` in the Immediate window.  This way you don't need to change the code.

Comment: I did not understand your answer.could you please explain it?

Comment: Sure, when Visual Studio has hit a breakpoint (that is, when you're able to see the values of variables by hovering the mouse over them), you should be able to see the Immediate Window in Visual Studio. (If not, open it by selecting from the main menu Debug -> Windows -> Immediate). In this window, type whatever you want to see the value of - for example myPart->bat_qty() and press Enter.

Comment: This solution has the disadvantage that the immediate window has to "execute" the function on myPart and as such apply its side effects in order to print out the result. I can give an example where this might cause puzzling behavior at lest (i.e program prints out something else if debugger is attached and the immediate window is used than if the immediate window is not used at all). The example is a little bit too long for a comment... Using the Autos window does not have this disadvantage and one does not have to type anything.

Comment: @ds27680 I do agree that this should only be used for simple functions (i.e. not functions that can potentially produce "puzzling behaviour").  But I'm not sure how else you can get the return value of a function without running it at least once, and for 99.9% of cases (all but perhaps the most complicated functions) where it's needed, it should suffice.

Comment: @Matt I posted a solution (using Autos window) that does not have this disadvantage I mentioned. However I must say that I did not know one can use the Immediate Window to call out functions, so I learned something new today. Thanks It's a nice to know :-)

Comment: @ds27680 ah I'm with you, didn't realise that was your answer.  I didn't know about that method... just goes to show you what a behemoth Visual Studio really is!

Comment: @Matt +1 for the behemoth :-)

Answer (score 3):

In VS 2010 you can put the breakpoint at the function call site and activate the "Autos" Window (if the Autos window is not visible you can make it visible from Debug -> Windows -> Autos Ctrl + Alt + V, A). In the Autos Window after you step over the function call (F10) you will see something in the lines of:

### Name                     Value         Type

[Func] Returned            [Return Value]        [Return Type]

where [Return Value] and [Return Type] are the appropriate return value and type for your function named [Func].

I hope this helps.

This has the advantage that you do not have to edit the code. The disadvantage I see is that if the returned type is complex you cannot expand it and inspect its attributes like you can do if you assign the return value to an automatic variable. However for simple structs the return value is expanded to something like this: {var1=[val1], var2=[val2]...} where var1, var2 are the attributes of the struct.

As far as I know the Autos Window is there (and did the same thing) back in VS 6.0 so this applies to VS 2005 too I guess (someone asked about VS 2005 too).

Comment: Apart from the "Autos" window, you can open the "Watch" window as well. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290591(VS.71).aspx (Though the link says VS 2003 .NET, the description applies to later versions as well).

Comment: @anand.arumug I'm not certain that you can get the returned value in "Watch". How would you do it? I ask so that I learn something new.

Comment: In watch window you can only see it only by stepping into the function using F11 and then figure out the value at the end of the function. Its a manual process. I specified Watch window as another means to see values of variables.

Answer (score 2):

Assign them to a temporary, like this :

```
const double bat_qty_val = myPart->bat_qty();
const double AUB_val = myPart->AUB();
```

then use those in the equation instead of calling functions.

Comment: ah snap :) +1 for the example ;)

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, and Im sure there would be a more elegant way, but you could assign the return values of bat_qty() and AUB() to a temporary variable and watch them in the debugger.

Comment: See @VJo answer for an example